# Question being asked when I enter Canada on a tourist visa. I am 26 years old with Indian NAtionality

Tags: indian-citizens, canada

I am travelling to Canada, Montreal on 4th July. I was wondering which questions do they ask at the time of immigration. Please, if someone has already been through it, reply.

Comment: You are getting close votes as the question is too broad. Everyone gets slightly different questions, depending on their circumstances and how they answer. Have a look at Border Patrol Canada on YouTube to get an idea.